# how to make gradient background

Tags: java, android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqBx7.jpg)

Please help me handle the following case in Android Studio Java, I want to make a gradient background image whose color flows from black to the main color of the main image as shown below.Please help me